# How do I implement the color I have on vertex paint onto my faces?

Tags: 3d-view, vertex-colors

I have painted my object with vertex-color on vertex-paint. How can I make the color visible in object-mode or edit-mode.

Meaning, how do I implement the vertex-color onto my faces so that I can see them on object-mode or edit-mode?

Comment: If you bake your vertex colors to a texture, then you would be able to see them in solid view with *Textured Solid* enabled.

Comment: @gandalf3 +1: Good point, I thinked on **BAKE** too, but forget about the **Textured Solid**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 3D View, hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the right panel, then enale Textured Solid.

[image: Textured Solid]

Now in Object Mode and Edit Mode, you will see the vertex colors.

[image]

EDIT: This appears to only work with Blender Render.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex color is show in **3D View** depending of your **Viewport Shading**

One menu next to where you choose *Edit Mode*, *Object Mode*, *Vertex Paint*, etc., the icons look like spheres showing different textures. You can switch between them. To see your vertex paint, **Texture** is needed.

If you need vertex paint on your renders, it's another story
(*Vertex Color Paint* in *Properties Editor > Materials > Options*).

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to convert **Viewport shading: Texture** into **Viewport shading: Solid**?

Comment: There's no option to make Vertex Colors show in *Solid* mode like they do in *Texture* mode. It needed a change in the source code, not sure how easy or difficult it would be.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, check out my answer.  It seems that you can see the vertex colors even with the Viewport Shading button set to solid.

Comment: You're right, it works! I could bet it didn't work yesterday when I tried several combinations of the N-panel shading options...

Comment: @Garry Nice one :D