# Where is the Materials Options panel? Blender v2.78

Tags: vertex-paint, panel

I've been trying to work with vertex painting in Blender v2.78 cycles and I can't seem to find the Materials Options panel.

I am referencing the introduction provided on the [Blender 2.78 manual here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html). I went to the Material Options hyperlink in the manual (just above the image), and that wasn't too helpful either.

Where is the "Materials Options panel"?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: That page is for BI.. you're searching for them in Cycles. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/how-do-i-implement-the-color-i-have-on-vertex-paint-onto-my-faces. I found way to see vertex color directly only in Material shading mode which in 2.78 was improved.

Comment: @MrZak It seems finding the correct references would be very helpful. Thanks for noticing that. :)